# Only add the value if it doesn't already exist C#

Tags: c#

I have a string "value" in which I am adding my object "subject".

I also have a string "english" as a subject. For english, I have a value of "10" in my xml. However when I debug through the code, I get `Count = 2`

The values I get are:
`[0] : 10` and
`[1] : 10`

I just want to get one value of 10, How is it possible? The line causing the problem is

```
    value.Add(subject.english);
```

I would ideally want to get `Count = 1` and only `[0] : 10`

Comment: You need to post the code that is causing this problem. No way anyone can guess what your problem is from what you have given us

Comment: Use a `HashSet` maybe? Really unclear as your description doesn't match your code (sounds like it should be `subject.Add(value.english)`